# Generate line number / "index" within a range from a date seed value

Tags: bash, date, range, random-seed

I'm trying to create a bash script to display a word of the day. I have a dictionary file that on each line has a word and its definition.

I'd like to use `date` to get a unique value for each day. Like so

```
today=$(date '+%Y%m%d') # will return 20160616 (for today)
```

Now I'd like to use this value to generate a line number for me to grab from the dictionary file.

My dictionary is `86036` lines long so I need to convert `$today` to a value between `1` and `86036`.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Well, that depends on your definition of "best". Do you want to enumerate the dictionary entries in order? Do you want to pick one randomly? Is it alright to repeat an entry before all entries have been shown? etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can use remainder operator `%`, it will give value between 0 and the number on the right (not inclusive), so you need to add 1 to get what you want:

```
value=$((today % 86036 + 1))
```